# Create array of objects from bsondump exported json

Tags: mongodb, bson

I used bsondump to export a huge (69GB) file to json. I expected to get a valid json array, but instead the objects are not separated.

There is an option to create a json array using mongoexport. But this bson file was exported from another machine, and due to size and performance considerations I do not want to import this large file before I can use mongoexport to export it from the db instead.

How can I export a valid json array using bsondump?

**EDIT**

To give more background why I need to convert from a bson based mongodb export to json:

1) I was trying to use mongoexport to export a json directly from mongodb. Just like this:

```
mongoexport -d mydb -c notifications --jsonArray -o lv.json
```

The problem with this is that there is no progress available for the export, and it runs significantly slower than mongodump (e.g. it never finished before I had to stop). I'm putting significant strain on a production server. As I stated in my original question, it's not an option for that reason.

2) mongodump works way faster, likely because it doesn't have to convert to json and just dumps the internal data. It also showed progress, so I knew when it would finish. So that's the only thing I could run on the production server.

```
mongodump --db mydb
```

**Edit 2**

After exporting to .bson it is then possible to use bsondump to convert the .bson file into a .json file:

```
bsondump mydata.bson > mydata.json
```

To make the point clear here: bsondump has no --jsonArray option like mongoexport. So it cannot export a valid json array, but instead dumps multpiple root objects into one file. The result is an invalid document, which one would have to pre-parse.

**/Edit2**

3) I have basically two options: Importing the bson dump into a local db, and exporting it to a proper json file using mongoexport --jsonArray. Or find a way around bsondump itself not being able to export to a proper json array file. The third option, implementing a bson parser into my tool, is something that I'm not really keen off...

The large file size is **not** a problem for my tool. My tool is written in C++ and specialized for large data streams. I use rapidjson with a SAX parser under the hood, and filter out records via an own SQL-like evaluator. Memory usage is in the area of < 10MB usually since I use a SAX parser instead of DOM.

Comment: You wean `mongodump` from the database perhaps? Because the job of `bsondump` is to convert that output to JSON. If it came from `mongoexport` then it already is JSON or CSV since those are the only things supported. And you probably meant [`--jsonArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#cmdoption-jsonarray) from `mongoexport`, otherwise it's "newline" separated by default.

Comment: More to the point, if this is actually 69GB then it would be near pointless to create a file that is wrapped in "array" notation, since you clearly never want to actually load the full content into memory ( or at least I hope not ). So what you really should be asking is how to set up your "parser" that actually needs to read this JSON output ( or even the BSON directly ) to deal with the default "newline" separation. Because `--jsonArray` is really just a "hack" for dealing with lazy code that cannot be bothered setting up such things. And also meant for "small" data.

Comment: @NeilLunn Please see the updates to my question.

Comment: I see what you added and I think it simply re-enforces my point. You do not want a "jsonArray" like output here. Instead you should be reading the chunks and parsing on the boundaries rather than slurping everything into memory and running a parse over the full content. This is pretty easy stuff. But you are making it hard on yourself by asking all the wrong questions. I should have been able to point you to the correct ways to do this. Ask questions about those instead.

Comment: You might consider being more polite when you ask for help.

Comment: (Sorry. Point taken.)The objects read are the same: Whether I read the "chunks on the boundaries" or each object within a valid array. The difference is the json document as exported, without the records embedded within an array, plain and simple is no valid json document. Any application wanting to read this would needs it's own first parse step to overcome that the document is no valid json and has multiple root entries. I could "read on the boundaries" of the export, meaning I implement a pre-parse step in order to handle invalid json input. Possible. But pointless.

Comment: To be more direct. Your question you asked 10 hours ago is sitting on the point of closure for essentially being very unclear. Sure you are adding some more detail right now, but by and large you are starting to talk about a program for which "there is no code included in the question". Much like your initial "knee-jerk" response, you need to sit back and think about what is said here. Tools like `mongoimport` work quite happily without throwing brackets `[]` around strings. You are basically talking about your own version of such a thing.

Comment: So take a break. Have a think, and then you might have separate "small questions" about little parts of your program. But you "need to talk about your program" and "present relevant parts of code". Broad and abstract discussions of how other tools work "get closed". And for this question to come back from that brink would be a near miracle.

Comment: I have to disagree. There are probably others facing the same issue, namely bsondump not being able to export a proper and valid json document. While bsonexport is able to do so... I do know how I could **hack** it in my implementation. But I specifically asked about a general solution so that bsondump outputs a valid json... I take it: It isn't able to.

Comment: FWIW: I created a feature request here https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools/issues/100

Comment: Did u find any solution?? I am also facing the same problem.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer my own question: bsondump is currently missing the option to create a json array as output (like mongoexport's --jsonArray option). I've created a feature request [1] and maybe it will be added to a next version of bsondump.

Meanwhile, I've created a small tool for my purpose which converts my data into a json array.

[1] https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-1734

Comment: would you be willing to share your tool? Having the same challenge - tried everything I could come up with in C#

Comment: Only issue is that `bsondump` can't handle files above a certain size... even though you stream through it. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

I used this linux command to convert invalid to valid json:

```
sed -i -e '1s/^/[/' -e ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/,/g' -e '$s/$/]/' dump.json
```

careful because this command modifies the file, so execute it over a copy